# Get complex solution to differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm solving Laplace equation in spherical coordinates.
I do this by separating variable. One part of the equation reduces to

```
Y''[y]/Y[y] = - m^2
```

Where $m$ is a positive number
Now imposing that $Y[2 \pi] = Y[0]$.

```
DSolve[Y''[y]/Y[y] = -m^2 && Y[0] == Y[2 Pi],Y[y],y]
```

Now the solution I get is just the real part of $e^{i m\phi}$. How do i get this solution instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do i get this solution instead?

I am confused what is being asked. But this is too small to write in comment.

Solution by Mathematica is correct (you also have some syntax errors, you use `=` where it should be `==`. I assume this is due to copy/paste).

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = Y''[y]/Y[y] == -m^2
ic = Y[0] == Y[2*Pi]
sol = DSolveValue[{ode, ic}, Y[y], y]
```

$$
c_1 \cos (m y)-c_1 \cot (2 \pi  m) \sin (m y)+c_1 \csc (2 \pi  m) \sin (m y)
$$

If you mean you want the complex exponential form, then

```
TrigToExp[sol] // Simplify
```

$$
\frac{c_1 e^{-i m y} \left(e^{2 i m y}+e^{2 i \pi  m}\right)}{1+e^{2 i \pi  m}}
$$

If this is not what you mean, then please clarify.